How to work with DynamoDb Sets with DynamoDBDocumentClient from SDK v3?
I'm not able to find an official reference to working with sets with DynamoDBDocumentClient.
How to do all sets actions with TypeScript and AWS SDK v3?

How to create item with set property?
How to add elements to an existing set property?
How to remove elements from an existing set property?


DynamoDB's APIs are language agnostic. All of the API references for updating Sets can be found here

Thank you, but sorry, I'm unable to see how this can help me. Specifically, I'm still clueless as to how should I create an item with a set property using DynamoDBDocumentClient

In really unsure of the issue? DocumentClient infers the type based on the languages native type. So a Set would be defined as it always is: Set(["a","b","c"]).

That was not the case in SDK v2. I had to tinker with workarounds for years. Hence the question about v3

Looks like I found my answer:

So we just need to use plain native Set type.
Amazing ‍♂️
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-lib-dynamodb/
